# php str_replace new line lost

Tags: php, newline, str-replace

I have these lines:

```
Four41dk: folds 
Masuronike: folds
Four41dk is sitting out
```

And i replace with str_replace their names "Four41dk, Masuronike" for

```
<span class='bold'> $theirName </span: folds
<span class='bold'> $theirName </span: folds
etc...
```

This works greate but the problem is when the name is at the end of the string like:

```
Four41dk: folds 
Uncalled bet (73) returned to MASUR0N1KE
Four41dk is sitting out
```

Now when i replace the nicks i lost the new line after RETURNED TO MASURONIKE so the output is in one line like:

```
Uncalled bet (73) returned to <span>MASUR0N1KE </span> <span> Four41dk </span> is sitting out
```

How can i fix it please?

I think i would need something like:

REPLACE THE NAME FOR NAME WITH SPAN BUT WHEN THERE IS \n AFTER THE NAME KEEP IT THERE

Comment: Please, show your code

Comment: You mean the basic easy str replace what only replace the nick for variable where is stored nick with span ? Nothing else...

Answer (score 0):

```
str_replace(...) . "<br/>";
```

is it just HTML?

### Ok, you have:

```
Four41dk: folds 
Masuronike: folds
Four41dk is sitting out
```

In plain text and you wish to render that out in `HTML` as:

```
<span>Four41dk</span>: folds <br/>
<span>Masuronike</span>: folds <br/>
<span>Four41dk</span> is sitting out <br/>
```

Then, your PHP code should be:

```
$input = "Four41dk: folds \n" .
   "Masuronike: folds \n" .
   "Four41dk is sitting out \n";
$output = nl2br(str_replace('Four41dk', '<span>RTM</span>', $input));
echo $output;
```

I apologize the lack of generic code but it goes well with the op.

Comment: Take note to insert the `<br/>` tag at the end of the line.

Comment: i can't do it ofc because i am replacing the nick once at the start of sentence one in the middle sometimes at the end... and i can't do nick <br> fold... it would create two lines what should be in one line together... right?

Comment: @Trki uggly fix: `$line = str_replace($nick, "<span>$nick</span>", $line) . "<br/>";`

Comment: Read once again what i wrote please... or check the question again and then try imagine what happen with your "ugly" fix.

Comment: @Trki I don't understand your "start|middle|end" statement. I'm assuming you are reading something (maybe a file) as data and replacing line by line. If this isn't the correct assumption, then apart of doing your "old" `str_replace()` you could replace each `newline` by `<br/>` assuming again, you are rendering that piece of code in HTML.

Comment: i know this function... look ... i preg_match some text EXACTLY THIS TEXT WHAT I HAVE PUT IN THE FIRST "CODE" BLOCK IN QUESTION (Four41dk: folds 
Masuronike: folds
Four41dk is sitting out) THEN I USE STR_REPLACE WHAT REPLACE MY NAMES FOR NAMES WITH SPAN ... EVERYTHING WORKS GREAT... BUT WHEN I GET TO THE SITUATION WHERE MY REPLACING NICK IS AT THE END OF THE STRING (CODE BLOCK 3 IN MY QUESTION) THEN IT SOMEHOW DESTROY THE LINE FROM IT... IF I WOULD USE YOUR IDEA ... you are right it would solve the problem with newline BUUUUUT it would also add new line after each replaced nick...

Comment: @Trki I insists. We can't help you out if you don't specify your problem correctly. `HTML` does not renders new lines like `\n` character. You are doing two things wrong. First, your code, and second, you cannot state your problem correctly. In addition, you seems to not understand how to use `str_replace()`. Not even reading the `API` for functions like `nl2br`.

Comment: okay i used nl2br function on that block of text... it solved our problem BUT there is the "free space" you can see on the image http://img703.imageshack.us/img703/4973/ojnp.png and i need to get rid of it any ideas how? Or what caused the white space there?

Comment: Its probably a dirty way but i solved it by: $actionBeforeFlop = preg_replace("/\s{2,}/sm", "", nl2br($actionBeforeFlop)); If you will have better idea let me know.